# Restricting values in a table used in a FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join

This concerns Oracle SQL.

Considering the following 3 tables:

TRIP_SEGMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE TRIP_SEGMENT(
   SEG_ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
   DIRECTION VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
   DEPARTURE_LOCATION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   DESTINATION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   SEGMENT_PRICE NUMBER(5,2) NULL,
   TRIP_ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT chk_SEG_DIRECTION CHECK (DIRECTION IN ('Outbound','Inbound')),
   CONSTRAINT pk_SEGMENT PRIMARY KEY (SEG_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_TRIP_ID FOREIGN KEY (TRIP_ID) REFERENCES TRIP(TRIP_ID)
);
```

TRANSPORTATION:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSPORTATION(
   TRANSP_BOOK_ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
   TRANSP_PRICE NUMBER(5,2) NULL,
   DEPARTURE_DATE DATE NULL,
   ARRIVAL_DATE DATE NULL,
   EXT_BOOK_ID NUMBER(6) NULL,
   SEG_ID NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
   SERV_TYPE_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
   PARTNER_ID NUMBER(3) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_TRANSP_BOOK_ID PRIMARY KEY (TRANSP_BOOK_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_TRANSP_SEG_ID FOREIGN KEY (SEG_ID) REFERENCES TRIP_SEGMENT(SEG_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_TRANSP_SERV_ID FOREIGN KEY (SERV_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES SERVICE_TYPE(SERV_TYPE_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_TRANSP_PARTNER_ID FOREIGN KEY (PARTNER_ID) REFERENCES PARTNER(PARTNER_ID)
);
```

PARTNER:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTNER(
   PARTNER_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
   PARTNER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   CONTACT_FNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   CONTACT_LNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) NULL,
   PHONE_NO NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
   EMAIL VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   SERV_TYPE_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_PARTNER_ID PRIMARY KEY (PARTNER_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_PART_SERV_ID FOREIGN KEY (SERV_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES SERVICE_TYPE(SERV_TYPE_ID)
);
```

I wanted to create a `FULL OUTER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT TS.SEG_ID, TS.DEPARTURE_LOCATION, TS.DESTINATION, P.PARTNER_NAME
   FROM TRIP_SEGMENT TS
   FULL OUTER JOIN TRANSPORTATION T
    ON TS.SEG_ID = T.SEG_ID
   FULL OUTER JOIN PARTNER P
    ON T.PARTNER_ID = P.PARTNER_ID;
```

...but have it restricted to `PARTNER.PARTNER_ID < 6`. If I just add a `WHERE` clause at the end of the JOIN, this will restrict all the values to those where there is an association with `PARTNER.PARTNER_ID < 6`, therefore defeating the purpose of the FULL OUTER JOIN.

So far, I've come up with this solution:

First, create a table that only contains `PARTNER.PARTNER_ID < 6` :

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSPORTATION_PARTNER AS SELECT * FROM PARTNER WHERE PARTNER_ID < 6;
```

Then, use that table in the `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT TS.SEG_ID, TS.DEPARTURE_LOCATION, TS.DESTINATION, TP.PARTNER_NAME
   FROM TRIP_SEGMENT TS
   FULL OUTER JOIN TRANSPORTATION T
    ON TS.SEG_ID = T.SEG_ID
   FULL OUTER JOIN TRANSPORTATION_PARTNER TP
    ON T.PARTNER_ID = TP.PARTNER_ID;
```

This works fine and it demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve, however I was wondering if there is a way of doing in one single query AND using a subquery.

Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention, It's Oracle SQL. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @user2989408, that produces the same result as no restriction at all, i.e. all partners are listed.

Comment: Then you could use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for the last JOIN and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, just do something like :

```
SELECT TS.SEG_ID, TS.DEPARTURE_LOCATION, TS.DESTINATION, P.PARTNER_NAME
FROM TRIP_SEGMENT TS
FULL OUTER JOIN TRANSPORTATION T
   ON TS.SEG_ID = T.SEG_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                 FROM PARTNER 
                 WHERE PARTNER.PARTNER_ID < 6) P
   ON T.PARTNER_ID = P.PARTNER_ID;
```

Comment: Sorry answer submitted before I had finished :D

Answer (score 0):

You are placing restrictions on the rows to be selected so you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Try something like

```
SELECT TS.SEG_ID, TS.DEPARTURE_LOCATION, TS.DESTINATION, P.PARTNER_NAME
FROM TRIP_SEGMENT TS
    FULL OUTER JOIN TRANSPORTATION T
        ON TS.SEG_ID = T.SEG_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTNER P
        ON T.PARTNER_ID = P.PARTNER_ID AND P.Partner_ID = 6;
```

Comment: If I use a LEFT OUTER JOIN there I cannot see the partners that don't have any association with the other tables (just like a LEFT JOIN is supposed to do). Only a FULL OUTER JOIN will work. You can use my Create Table queries to test it.